# Can't go to next/previous edit point in Brackets with Emmet

Tags: text-editor, adobe-brackets, emmet

Support for Emmet's next and previous edit point seems to be missing or what? Every time I press CTRL+ALT+--> my screen rotates. This is happening on windows only.

EDIT: You can disable the default keyboard shortcuts in control panel but in that case any application won't be able to use those too, nor is there a way remap the keys in Brackets easily!

Comment: To those who who giving negative feedback try answering it. It ain't that easy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> All available keybindings are defined in keymap.json.

source: https://github.com/emmetio/brackets-emmet

To open this keymap file, first open Brackets, then go to **Help** > **Show Extensions Folder**. Open the **user** folder, then modify **keymap.json** to however you prefer your shortcuts. Reload Brackets Editor when finished.

My keymap was located in
`C:\Users\%username%\AppData\Roaming\Brackets\extensions\user\brackets-emmet`

You will need to change these two lines:

```
"next_edit_point": "Ctrl-Alt-Right",
"prev_edit_point": "Ctrl-Alt-Left",
```

Comment: Thanks a lot I had already tried binding CTRL+S+RIGHT and CTRL+S+LEFT but it didn't worked tried, now I tried again after seeing your comment with other keys and for some reason it did. I binded Ctrl-Shift-Alt-Right and Ctrl-Shift-Alt-Left.